# Which encryption algorithm does Entity Framework use to save passwords?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, encryption, passwords

I used the entity framework code first to create a simple CRUD web application in ASP.NET MVC 5. The MVC 5 came with ready to use registration and authentification. I want to know what's the encryption algorithm used to save pass words?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx is it OWIN? What auth module did you pick when you created the project?

Comment: I picked the individual user accounts

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework does save passwords. A saved password is hashed (You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them) in a layer before you pass it off to Entity Framework (if you pass the password down that far at all).

ASP.NET MVC 5 is that "layer before" and how it handles passwords depends on [which options you chose for security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security).

Comment: I used  individual user accounts

Comment: "Individual user accounts" is not a security mode. Please read through my and Charleh's links to learn what kinds of security modes there are.